# Node crash using express and static middleware when URL contains a trailing backslash

Tags: node.js, connect, express

I have a simple Express server that is serving up some static files.  Here is the server:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express.createServer();

// Configuration
app.configure(function() {
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.staticCache());
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
});

// 404
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.send('not found', 404);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

In my public directory I have a file called `index.html`.  Firing up `node app.js` and then browsing to `localhost:3000/index.html` shows the static file as expected.  Navigating to `localhost:3000/ind` or `localhost:3000/ind\` shows the `404` page as expected.

However, navigating to `localhost:3000/index.html\` (note the trailing backslash) crashes my `node` server with:

```
stream.js:105
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
        ^
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory  '/home/bill/projects/app/public/index.html\'
```

Why is the `node` server crashing instead of just serving up the `404` page?  I thought since the file does not exist, the static middleware would just skip it and pass the request on to the routes.  I got around it by creating a custom middleware that returns `404` if a trailing backslash exists in the request URL, but I'd like to figure out if I'm missing something here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this behavior seems to be the difference in how `fs.stat` and `fs.createReadStream` handle trailing backslashes.

When the string `'path/to/public/index.html\\'` [is given to `fs.stat`](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/static.js#L147) in the static middleware, it is ignored (running `stat index.html\` on the command line checks for a file named `index.html`, you'd have to run `stat index.html\\` for `index.html\`). So `fs.stat` thinks the file was found because it thinks you're asking for `index.html`, and doesn't call the next middleware handler.

Later, that string [is passed to `fs.createReadStream`](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/static.js#L223) which thinks it's looking for `index.html\`. It doesn't find that file and throws said error.

Since the functions treat the backslash differently, you can't really do anything but use some middleware to filter out those requests.

Comment: Looks like this is a bug in connect then, since having everyone write custom middleware doesn't make much sense. Especially since those that don't open themselves up to a very easy deny of service of attack. I'll file a bug. Thanks!

Comment: This issue has now been fixed in the current Connect code base.